# Making a callback in a chain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

Can we make a callback in a chain like this?

```
Widget.update(...).onUpdate(function(data){
   console.log('updated');
});
```

current code,

```
var Gateway = {};

Gateway.put = function(url, data, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: true,
        success: function (returndata,textStatus, jqXHR) {
            callback(returndata);
        }
    });
};


var Plugin = function() {};

Plugin.prototype = {

    update : function(options, callback) {
        /// other stuff
        Gateway.put($url, $data, function(data){
            callback(data);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

usage,

```
    var Widget = new Plugin();

    Widget.put({
        button: options.button
    }, function(data){
        console.log('updated');
    });
```

but ideally,

```
Widget.update(...).onUpdate(function(data){
       console.log('updated');
    });
```

**EDIT:**

at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mhhvnfqd/1/).

Comment: Use promises. http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: Make the ajax methods return a promise and then use that like: `Widget.update(...).done(function(data){
   console.log('updated');
});` or use events...

Comment: i get an error of `TypeError: Widget.put(...).done is not a function` with `.done()`. i would prefer avoiding jquery as much as possible.

Comment: @tealou If you're using $.ajax, you mightaswell use the promise that was returned from it. If you ever drop jquery for another library, you can still use promises even if said library doesn't provide them.

Comment: Why did you tag jquery in your question then?

Comment: how do i make `promises`??

Comment: If I am understanding your purpose correctly, you can use the 'complete' function of $.ajax right after 'success' function, like `complete: function(){ //do your stuff }`, which will trigger it when the ajax call is completed.

Comment: yes i know that. but i don't want to handle the ajax responses inside jquery's  ajax's `success:...` - it makes messy codes in the end.

Comment: "how do i make `promises`" In ES6 it's built-into the js engine, but for now there are libraries that you can include. jQuery has it's own promise system that you can use by simply adding a `return`. `return $.ajax(...` as suggested in @simonstaton's answer (the second snippet)

Comment: tried that but get an error though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really like the *callback hell* coding style, but sometimes it hurts. As suggested by other users, have you already heard about [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)?

> The core idea behind promises is that a promise represents the result of an asynchronous operation.

As suggested in the link above - that proposed a standard for them - once polyfill'd the browser using

```
<script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-done-6.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

you will be able to create `new Promise`'s, hence to use their nice `done()` attribute.

You will end up with

```
Plugin.prototype.update = function (options) {
    return new Promise(function (fullfill, reject) {
        Gateway.put($url, $data, function (data) {
            fullfill(data);
        });
    });
};
```

That is, `Plugin.prototype.update` returns a promise.

```
Widget.update(...).done(function(data){
    console.log('updated');
});
```

I have not tested the code, but the *spirit* is that. :)

**EDIT**: Using promises is awesome. I simply don't like when people discover them, use them in newer parts of the codebase but finally do not refactor the rest of it.

Comment: Why use this 3rd party lib when hes already performing an $.ajax request which will return a deferred.promise?

Comment: javascript has `promise` itself too. take a look. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: it prompts a futher question, why jquery and why this plugin?

Comment: @tealou, the reason jquery came out was because you use `$.ajax` -- that is a wrapper around the native `XMLHttpRequest` object, which you can use if you want to get rid of jQuery.

Comment: @tealou, yeah I find it later. Yet, without polyfilling the browser you won't have a `done` method but only the `then` one. The code is not different really.

Comment: Yea it is not difficult. i'm going to invest sometime in it and getting rid of jquery :D thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do will work however you need to pass your callback to update

```
Widget.update(yourOptions, function(data){
       console.log('updated');
    });
```

You could also return your ajax request directly and chain onto it

```
var Gateway = {};

Gateway.put = function(url, data) {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        async: true
    });
};


var Plugin = function() {};

Plugin.prototype = {

    update : function(options) {
        /// other stuff
        return Gateway.put($url, $data);
    }
}

var Widget = new Plugin();

Widget.update(yourOptions).done(function() {
  console.log('updated');
});
```

Comment: sorry, i get this error `TypeError: Widget.put(...).done is not a function`

Comment: Can you post Widget.put() as you did not supply that method in your original post

Comment: Your not returning anything in that fiddle from my above answer, try this http://jsfiddle.net/r4d9mgsq/ although I can't test myself.

Comment: tried that already and it is an error. never mind thanks for the help.